# Выбор определенных слов php

Tags: php

К примеру у нас есть строка "слово, что-то, 3, ХешКод, 5, ..., и.тп" 
Как нам записать в массив только слова до запятой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это, если вы имеете ввиду записать в новую строку все символы до запятой:

```
 $text = "123 fddsf , ewffdsgsdfg";
    $pos = strpos($text,",");
    $newtext=substr($text,0,$pos);

    echo $newtext;
```

А это, если разбить строку на массив, считая границами запятые:

```
$text = "слово, что-то, 3, ХешКод, 5, ..., и.тп";
$arr = explode(',',$text);

echo("<pre>");
print_r($arr);
echo("<pre>");
```

Comment: В этом варианте оно напишет только 123 fddsf а мне надо, чтобы и 123 fddsf и ewffdsgsdfg

Comment: Дополнил ответ)

Comment: Я бы еще через trim() прогнал, если это именно слова

Comment: Можно и прогнать.